# When do I need to specify the type in the second <> of a template specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have a base template:

```
template <class X> void f(X x) {}
```

Now I have seen two ways to specialize it:

```
template <> void f<>(int x) {}
```

Or:

```
template <> void f<int>(int x) {}
```

gcc eats both variants, but not both at the same time.

Are these two specializations the same? When do I need to specify type in the second <> when specializing a template?

Comment: I would say they are the same, the second one would come in handy when the signature of the function would not change.

Comment: Don't overload template functions, just write a normal one, e.g. `void f(int x) {}`

Comment: @billz That would be an overload. What should be avoided here is specialization.

Comment: I am aware of http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm In fact that page is the reason why I asked this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your variants perform the same specialization. You can also use a third variant

```
template <> void f(int x) {}
```

which will also specialize the function template for `X = int`. It is equivalent to your second variant.

Variants with `f<>` and plain `f` rely on template argument deduction, while the `f<int>` variant specifies the template argument explicitly.

You might need to specify the type in `<>` explicitly when template argument deduction is impossible. In other cases you don't have to do it.

For example, if your function argument list did not depend on the template parameter `X`, then you'd have no choice but to specify the template argument explicitly

```
template <typename X> void bar() {}

template <> void bar<int>() {}
```

The above compiles. But if you replace the specialization with

```
template <> void bar<>() {}
```

it will fail to compile because the compiler cannot deduce the template argument.

Answer (score 2):

The two specializations are the same. `template<>` always specializes an existing template, rather than declaring a new signature. If deduction from the specialization parameter types can determine what goes inside `<>`, then you are allowed to omit that part. (Leaving such things out may be a bad idea if there are more template overloads. It could become unclear which template is being specialized.)

By the way, specializing functions is usually a bad idea. Overload resolution will prefer a non-template overload and effectively hide the specialization you wish to prevent. Rather than combining the overloading and specialization mechanisms, just stick to overloading.